# While loop and logical operators in Python - how does it work?

Tags: python, loops, logical-operators

Why is it that when I type the code:

```
A = 0
B = 0

while A<10 or B<5:
    A+=1
    B+=1
    print(A)
    print(B)
```

the loop doesn't stop when B=5; instead, it continues to add 1 to both A and B until A = 10, then it stops. The same thing happens when I swap the order, like:

```
while B<5 or A<10:
```

When I replaced 'or' with 'and', the code stops when B=5, just the way I wanted. I'm just confused as to how 'or' and 'and' actually works.

Comment: `and` means both conditions must be true. `or` means at least one must be true. so `A<10 or B<5` is true as long as `A<10` is true, that's why it continued until A=10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's similar to English:

- `or` gives `True` when **any** of the conditions on both sides are `True`.
- `and` gives `True` when **all** of the conditions on both sides are `True`.

Answer (score 0):

`A` < 10 and B < `5` means that your loop while continue while `A` is less than `10` **AND** `B` is less than `5` (checking both conditions) or in other words, it will only stop if when `A` has a value more than or equal to `10` **OR** `B` has a value that is more than or equal to `5` (any one of the two).

As for `A` < 10 or B < `5`, the loop will continue if `A` has a value that is less than `10` **OR** `B` has a value that is less than `5` (any one of the two). That is, if `A = 10` and `B = 2` the loop will still continue because `B` still fulfills the condition. The loop will only terminate if `A` has a value that is more than or equal to 10 **AND** `B` has a value that is more than or equal to `5` (the two has to be true).